# How to set typescript index signature as value of interface inline?

Tags: typescript

In order to get better tips when hovering over my library code, I want to inline the following code:

```
interface Tags {
  [Key: string]: string | number | boolean | symbol | null | undefined
}

export interface Context {
  tags?: Tags
  otherValues?: number 
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it worked!!

```
export interface Context {
  tags?: { [Key: string]: string | number | boolean | symbol | null | undefined }
  otherValues?: number 
}
```

Also another approach is to use Record:

```
export interface Context {
  tags?: Record<string, string | number | boolean | symbol | null | undefined>
  otherValues?: number 
}
```